# Custom color range in r plot_ly scatter

Tags: r, plot, shiny, colors, r-plotly

I am struggling with setting a custom range / cutoff for the colour values in a plot_ly scatter plot.

```
data(mtcars)

plot_tmp <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, 
                    marker = list(size=10, colorbar = "Hot"),
                    hovertext = ~mtcars[,3],
                    type = "scatter",
                    x = ~mtcars[,1], 
                    y = ~mtcars[,2], 
                    color = ~mtcars[,3]) 

plot_tmp
```

[image: Plot example]

I tried using colorbar(limits = c(3,5)), but this only excludes everything from beeing coloured.

```
plot_tmp %>% colorbar(limits = c(250,350))
```

[image: Plot using "limits"]

The desired output would be to set everything e.g. over the limit to the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of reading in the manual I was able to come up with a working solution:

```
plot_tmp <- plot_ly(
  data = mtcars,
  x = ~ mtcars[, 1],
  y = ~ mtcars[, 2],
  mode = "markers",
  type = "scatter",
  marker = list(
    size = "3em",
    color = ~ mtcars[, 3],
    cauto = FALSE,
    colorbar = list(title = "Scaled Expression"),
    cmin = 250,
    cmax = 280
  ),
  hovertext = ~ mtcars[, 3]
)
plot_tmp
```

The important thing is specifying the **color**, **cmin** and **cmax** argument inside of the list of "**marker**".
If you don't specify the color inside, the scale bar will not be updated according to your min and max values